# Parser Error with HIVE ODBC

Tags: c#, odbc, hive

I'm writing some code in C# to invoke a HIVE script via ODBC. I'm using the Hortonworks Hive ODBC Driver (though I've tried several others as well and I get the same error). I can connect fine via ODBC and simple commands work perfectly (for example SELECT * FROM MyTable LIMIT 10; will do exactly what it should). Where I run into trouble is with longer scripts that we have for processing where they have multiple 'chunks' of SQL (each terminated by a semi-colon). So for example, the first statement usually creates a temp table, the next inserts into it, then maybe another select from a different table, etc, typical SQL. But I keep getting the following error on the line that specifies the S3 location for the file with a parser error:

**Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 8:85 missing EOF at ';' near ''s3n://somebucket/somefolder/etc'**

Here's an example of where this is failing:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytesttable(
   id int,
   anotherid int,
   name string   
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
LOCATION 's3n://somebucket/somefolder/etc';

...script continues here with the next chunk of SQL
```

What am I doing wrong? 
Also, if I SSH in and run this script from the command line it works perfectly.

Comment: Interesting wrinkle to add. If I remove all the lines in the script below the part above (i.e. after the LOCATION line) it runs perfectly. It's like it doesn't like multiple statements but I can't figure out why. Like I said it works if I run it from a command line.

Comment: Just for clarity, are you able to run multiple statements within a single query from the command line (which tool?), but not within the ODBC driver?

Comment: @KylePorter Yes, if I point to the script file in S3 it works fine. Also if I schedule an EMR step that points to the script file it runs perfectly. It's only when I attempt to send the script as a call thru the ODBC driver that it fails. As far as I can tell it does not like the fact that there are multiple statements within the script, if I run a single statement via ODBC it seems to behave as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in testing, the hive shell will accept multiple statements in a query. It does this by breaking the query into multiple separate statements and issuing them to Hive as separate queries.

The ODBC drivers do not currently work with multi-statement queries, if you're interested in having that capability added you should contact the distribution you got the ODBC driver from, or you can contact Simba (http://www.simba.com/connectors/apache-hadoop-hive-driver) if you're using the Apache distribution as they create the technology used by most distributions.